# Get list of datetime object for repeating time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, repeat, python-datetime

**The problem:**

I have this list of specific time, for example:

```
repeat = ['8:15','14:28','19:43','1:21']
```

Now I am trying to create a function that would output a list of *n* number of datetime objects like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 17, 5, 55, 908000) # 2018-10-30 17:05:55
>>> 
>>> output = magic(repeat, how_many=3) # <---
>>> output
[datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 19, 43), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 1, 21), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 8, 15)]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for i in output:
>>>     print( i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") )

2018-10-30 19:43:00
2018-10-31 01:21:00
2018-10-31 08:15:00
```

**My progress:**

So I tackled this issue with this solution:

```
def next(datetime_object, repeat):
    # this function should calculate the next datetime from the datetime_object

    return next_datetime_object

def magic(repeat, how_many=10):
    converted = []
    for i in repeat:
        converted.append( datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%H:%M') )

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    output = [ next(now,converted) ]

    while len(output) < how_many:
        output.append(
            next(output[-1] ,converted)
            )

    return output
```

Though I got stuck in creating this function `next()` which should calculate the next datetime object.

Also if anyone has any other alternative solution that is better than mine, please share it with me.

---

**Edit 1 (just for clarification)**

Input: `repeat = ['8:15','14:28','19:43','1:21']`

Function: `magic(repeat, how_many=3)`

Output: `[ datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 19, 43), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 1, 21), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 8, 15) ]`

Note: the output is dependent on the current `datetime.datetime.now()`. In the example above, the current time was `datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 17, 5, 55, 908000)`

Comment: Can you provide which is the expected output based on the input?

Comment: Check the _Edit 1_. Expected output is a list of datetime objects.

Comment: How should one choose the output datetimes based on the current datetime, at random? Or should one take the date from the current datetime and then output up to 4 datetimes taking from the list in order?

Comment: In order. So basically, the list shows _allowed_ times. And I need to get list of the NEAREST (CLOSEST) _allowed_ time.

Comment: and the list is in order from the nearest allowed time to the furthest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to create [`datetime.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) objects, then make the sequence cyclic with [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [combine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) these with [`datetime.date` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date):

```
import datetime
from itertools import cycle, product, repeat
from bisect import bisect

def datetime_series(*timestrings, reference=None):
    times = sorted(datetime.time(*map(int, t.split(':'))) for t in timestrings)
    if reference is None:
        reference = datetime.datetime.now()
    date, tnow = reference.date(), reference.time()

    next_pos = bisect(times, tnow)  # index of next time object to use
    times = cycle(times + [None])
    for _ in range(next_pos):  # skip forward across the time objects
        next(times)

    for time in times:
        if time is None:
            # next day
            date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            time = next(times)
        yield datetime.datetime.combine(date, time)
```

The above uses `None` as a sentinel to detect that a the date value needs to be incremented a step, and the time strings are accepted as separate arguments, and you can pass in a different reference date (the default is to use *now*).

It's also an endless a generator, so you can iterate over it step by step, or use `itertools.slice()` to limit the number of results.

Personally, I'd alter make the function accept `datetime.time()` objects rather than pass in strings, so you just sort the arguments without having to parse and go from there.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 17, 39, 46, 91967)
>>> m = datetime_series('8:15', '14:28', '19:43', '1:21')
>>> next(m)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 19, 43)
>>> next(m)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 1, 21)
>>> m = datetime_series('8:15', '14:28', '19:43', '1:21')
>>> ten_results = list(islice(m, 10))
>>> pprint(ten_results)
[datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 19, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 1, 21),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 8, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 14, 28),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 19, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 1, 21),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 8, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 14, 28),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 19, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 2, 1, 21)]
>>> question_1 = datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 31, 21, 26, 37)  # https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/30138
>>> question_1_series = datetime_series('8:15', '14:28', '19:43', '1:21', reference=question_1)
>>> pprint(list(islice(question_1_series, 10)))
[datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 1, 1, 21),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 1, 8, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 1, 14, 28),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 1, 19, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 2, 1, 21),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 2, 8, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 2, 14, 28),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 2, 19, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 3, 1, 21),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 3, 8, 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to create date time objects till it reaches the how_many. Then sort it and return the first how_many items.

Sample code is

```
import datetime as dt

def magic(repeat, how_many=3):
    output = []
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    next_day = now
    while len(output) < how_many:
        nextFormated = next_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        next_times = [dt.datetime.strptime(nextFormated + " " + s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for s in repeat if dt.datetime.strptime(nextFormated + " " + s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") > now]
        next_day += dt.timedelta(days=1)
        output = output + next_times
    output.sort()
    return output[:how_many]

repeat = ['8:15','14:28','19:43','1:21']
op = magic(repeat, 10)
print(dt.datetime.now())
print(op)
```

Output is

```
2018-10-30 23:07:52.635834
[datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 1, 21), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 8, 15), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 14, 28), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 19, 43), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 1, 21), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 8, 15), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 14, 28), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 19, 43), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 2, 1, 21), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 2, 8, 15)]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```